# What does the number in R{number} after a git rename mean?

Tags: git, rename

I made the commit below. It basically shows a couple of files with static html getting renamed and moved.

```
commit 8449e207d529779f92bfe8b4eb2864a3f3edf69a
Author: Carl-Erik Kopseng <carl-erik@company.no>
Date:   Sat Nov 19 14:40:47 2016 +0100

    Integrate static html into epi blocks as partials

R079    Web/Views/Shared/Blocks/ChristmasLotteryBlock.cshtml    Web/Views/Shared/Blocks/ChristmasLotteryBlock/Index.cshtml
R076    Web/Static/blocks/_block_christmas-lottery-intro.html   Web/Views/Shared/Blocks/ChristmasLotteryBlock/_intro.cshtml
R099    Web/Static/blocks/_block_christmas-lottery-popup.html   Web/Views/Shared/Blocks/ChristmasLotteryBlock/_popup.cshtml
M       Web/Web.csproj
```

What does the 076, 099 and 079 refer to? I get that R probably stands for "Rename".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [the `git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

> Status letters C and R are always followed by a score (denoting the
>    percentage of similarity between the source and target of the move or
>    copy). Status letter M may be followed by a score (denoting the
>    percentage of dissimilarity) for file rewrites.

(You will only see M followed by a number if you are using the `-B` flag.  Here is a somewhat contrived example of adding `-B` to cause an `M` status to have an appended score:

```
$ git diff --raw -M HEAD~182 | grep 'M[0-9]'
$ git diff --raw -B -M HEAD~182 | grep 'M[0-9]'
:100644 100644 2b1487d... bdb5579... M074   Makefile
:100644 100644 b639986... 8d8ebfe... M067   fcall.h
:100644 100644 bc4f828... 2e07ef6... M060   lib9p.h
:100644 100644 f9b5d18... 15e1ae8... M066   request.c
```

This particular repository has 184 first-parent commits starting from HEAD:

```
$ git rev-list --count --first-parent HEAD
184
```

with many—though not all—files appearing within the first few commits, so that comparing `HEAD~182` to `HEAD` has many changes that result in many broken pairings when using `-B`.)

Comment: What is -B? I don't see that option anywhere in `git help status`. Not only that, the combination of characters "-B" is not on that page at all.

Comment: @trysis: `git status` does not offer the break-pairings option; that's only available in other `git diff` front ends. The question did not state which command the OP was using to get the output he showed (though I was guessing it was `git show --stat`, which *does* provide `-B`).